# Ссылка на текущий активити

Tags: java, android

У меня несколько активити и Navigation Drawer Menu... Если нахожусь в других активити то при нажатии на первую ссылку он должен открыть MainActivity а если нахожусь на главной странице то по нажатии на нее ничего не должно происходить... И даже веденные данные должны остаться без изменений. Так вот в моем случает он тупо создает новый активити с пустыми данными...
Как правильно сделать помогите...?

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_search) {
        intent = new Intent(this, Main.class)
                .addFlags(
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вы можете проверить каким классом является `Context` (`this` в коде)  с помощью оператора `instanceof` и соответственно реагировать:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_search) {
        if(this instanceof Main) {//вы уже в главной активити}
        else
        {
             intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Наверное логичнее использовать условие `!(this instanceof Main)` и обойтись без `else`, раз уж при нахождении в `Main` делать ничего не нужно.

Comment: @pavlofff, да всё верно, просто я решил не сокращать ради помещения коммента в коде, для наглядности)